# How to calculate efficiently and accurately the Fourier transform of a radial function in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fft, fortran90, continuous-fourier

As my question states, I want to calculate the Fourier transform F(q) of a radial function f(r) (defined on [0,infinity[ and which decays like an exponential exp(-Ar +b) at large r) as accurately as possible in Fortran. The function values come from a data file (which I can easily interpolate through cubic interpolation for example and extrapolate since the behaviour at large r is known).

I'm using the "physics" definition of the Fourier transform in 3D, which gives (because f is radial) : [image]

I first tried to calculate this integral for some chosen values of q by using Gauss-Legendre quadrature, by generating some 60 or 100 abscissas and weights via the NAG routine D01BCF ([D01BCF link)](http://www.nag.com/numeric/fl/manual/pdf/D01/d01bcf.pdf). In the case of Gauss Legendre quadrature, the problem is to choose the interval [0,B] on which to integrate. While the function f loses 4 to 5 orders of magnitude from r=10 to r=20 (example), the choice of B as a strong influence on the result of the calculation... When I compared the result I get to a "nearly exact" calculation (made with matlab but with a veeeery long computation time), I saw that in fact this was only valid for small values of q (of the order of 5, when I have to deal with values as large as 150). A Gauss-Laguerre quadrature does not give any better result, probably because of the oscillatory part of the integrand.

I then tried to compute this Fourier transform for some given values of q with the routine D01ASF [(D01ASF link)](http://www.nag.com/numeric/fl/manual/pdf/D01/d01asf.pdf). It is a "one-dimensional quadrature, adaptive, semi-infinite interval, weight function cos(ωx)  or sin(ωx) ", which is exactly what I need. The results are quite convincing for q up to 80 or 100 if I input absolute error tolerances of 10E-5. Problems are : I would need to go at larger q, and the Fourier transform F(q) oscillates with a magnitude of ~ 10E-6 at such q's. Lowering the tolerance to 10E-5 already takes some time and even makes the whole thing to output some error message from the subroutine so I don't know if 10E-6 would be feasible.

I'm thus currently wondering if trying to calculate this Fourier transform with FFT wouldn't be a good idea ? The problems I face are that I don't know how to calculate radial wave functions with FFT (and also that I don't even know how to use FFT properly either since the definition of the transform is not even the same (exponent sign and argument) and that I never used it before).

Would you have ideas ? :)

EDIT 2 : I tried by FFT (using the routine [C06FAF](http://www.nag.com/numeric/fl/manual/pdf/C06/c06faf.pdf) from NAG library). It works quite well up to some large values of q. The problem I face is that there is always some constant normalising factor to account for. I don't get why. This normalising factor evolves with the number N of points used in the mesh. It has the for of a power law : Normalising Factor F = N^(-0.5) x exp(9.9) approximately (see figure [image: figure] where the black line is the "exact" Fourier Transform and the green, magenta, blue, red and yellow lines are the FFT calculated for different values of N)

EDIT3 : I found the factor to be A*N^(-0.5) where A is the length of the integration mesh

Comment: one bit of advice is to test your quadrature schemes using an analytic `f(r)` for which you have an exact solution. ( `f(r)=Exp(-r)` for example )

Comment: My idea is to post this question at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com and remove it from here.

Comment: @agentp I tried by FFT and I get some weird result when I compare the analytical FT(exp(-r)) to the computed one. There seems to be a normalising factor to take care of (look also at the EDIT)

Comment: @agentp Also, at some point, the Fourier transform calculated by FFT (for exp(-r)) drops (at the end of the frequencies mesh). I tested it for some fermi dirac distribution (1/exp((r-R)/a)) and it also diverges at some point (and quite soon...)

Comment: A scale factor of `n**(-0.5)` in the definition of the transform is mentioned in the documentation.  Are you saying that you see a factor beyond that?

Comment: I found the factor. It is actually A*N**(-0.5) where [0,A] is the interval of the calculation.

Comment: The FFT algorithm calculates the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) which is a poor approximation to the continuous Fourier transform (FT). It calculates the integral with a rectangular rule or Rieman sum so it is not vey accurate. Quadpack from [link](http://nines.cs.kuleuven.be/software/QUADPACK/) has a quadrature subroutine for oscillating integrands (I think it's called QDAG). Unfortunately, speed and accuracy conflict with each other.